# Javascript - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier Javascript- Php

Tags: javascript, php

The problem is that I try to pass more than one parameter in the function onchange = showService (pase, tipo, fecha) these parameters I get them by get in php and convert the variables to javascript format like this:

```
<? Php
$ tipo = $ _ GET ['tipo'];
$ pase = $ _ GET ['pase'];
$ fecha = $ _ GET ['fecha'];
?>
<Script>
tipo = <? Php echo $ tipo; ?>
pase = <? Php echo $ pase; ?>
fecha = <? Php echo $ fecha; ?>
</ Script>
```

And it does not work, it only recognizes the first parameter and if I just date it in this format (2017-02-22) when painting the received with ajax I painted "1993" and therefore the query does not do it well and I get The table empties.

And if I write directly the url getservice.php passing the variables the query does it correctly.

This is complete code

index2.php

```
<?php require('config.php'); ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .relleno {
        background-color: cadetblue;
        height: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid goldenrod;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function showService(pase,tipo,fecha)

    {

    if (tipo=="" && pase=="" && fecha=="")

      {

      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";

      return;

      }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)

      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

      }

    else

      {// code for IE6, IE5

      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

      }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()

      {

      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)

        {

        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

        }

      }

    xmlhttp.open('GET','getservice2.php?pase='+pase+'&tipo='+tipo+'&fecha='+fecha,true);


    xmlhttp.send();

    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Selecciona una opción para cargar su información mediante las técnicas AJAX</h1>
    <div class="relleno"></div>

    <?php 
    $pase=$_GET[pase];
    $tipo=$_GET[tipo];
    $fecha=$_GET[fecha];
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    pase== <?php echo $pase; ?>  
    tipo== <?php echo $tipo; ?>
    fecha== <?php echo $fecha; ?>

    </script>

    <form>
      <select name="services" onChange="showService(pase,tipo,fecha)">
        <option value="">Seleccione número de personas...</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>             
      </select>    
        <?php
    /*
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT service_id, title, price, date_added, date_modified, status FROM services ORDER BY title asc", $conexion);

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

                echo '<option value="'.$row['service_id'].'">'.$row['title'].'</option>';

            }
    */
            ?>

    </form>
    <br />
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Seleccina un servicio de la lista para ver su información.</b></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

getservice2.php

```
            <?php
            require('config.php');

            $pase = $_GET[pase];
            $tipo = $_GET[tipo];
            $fecha = $_GET[fecha];


            $consulta="SELECT * FROM pase_completo WHERE idshow_tipo = '".$tipo."' AND idpase_tipo = '".$pase."' AND fecha = '".$fecha."'";
            echo $consulta;

            $query = mysql_query($consulta, $conexion);

            echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <th>personas</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th>Fecha de registro</th>
            <th>Fecha de modificacion</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            </tr>";

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['personas'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['date_added'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['date_modified'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }

            echo "</table>";



            mysql_close($conexion);

            ?>
```

Many Thanks

Comment: I don't think php variable names can have a space after the `$` symbol.

Comment: Where???? i don´t look